# Scrollbars for Struts 2 tiles

Tags: css, struts2

I am using Struts  tiles. I have a header, menu and body. I want to have scrollbars for the menu section only. I am getting scrollbar for the whole page but want it just for the menu section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a scrollable div.  Take a look at the following link from w3schools which provides code and an example of this very problem.

[CSS solution by w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

[Example, which you can modify, by w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)

In the example, try changing the width of the div to 100% instead of 100px to have it be the entire width of the page.

Comment: Thank u Michael...got an idea on how to fix it...Thanks again !!